# How do I Uninstall Windows 10 or Windows 10 preview?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-preview

I joined in the [preview program](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preview) and I don't like it. However, this question may also be relevant to those who install the full version of Windows 10.

How can I downgrade back to Windows 8/7 from Windows 10 or Windows 10 preview?

[Same question for Windows 8](https://superuser.com/questions/395719/how-do-i-uninstall-windows-8-consumer-preview)

Comment: Please note I read the terms and conditions and it had nothing about reversion. I didn't actually install it.

Comment: I am not sure how I feel about this question.  I mean the answer is exactly the same as it was for Windows 8's preview versions, unless you create a recovery image of course.

Comment: @Ramhound, the question is at the very least a useful canonical question we can use to close the hundred other dupes that are about to hit us.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**For Windows 10**

> To roll back your Windows 10, go to your PC Settings, by typing Settings in the taskbar search bar, next to the Windows icon, and clicking on Settings. It will open the PC Settings. Select ‘Update and Security’.
>
> The Update and Security option opens. Here you will see options like Windows Update, Activation, Backup, Recovery and Windows Defender. Click on 'Recovery'.
>
> This will open the Recovery settings window for your PC. You will see 3 options:
>
> - Reset this PC: Remove everything and reinstall Windows. This will take your PC to its original factory settings.
> - Go back to your previous version of Windows: This will just bring your previous Windows back on your PC without affecting your documents and files. Note that you have to carry out the rollback operation, within 30 days of upgrading to Windows 10
> - Advanced Startup: Here you can change your PC settings using a Windows image or a USB/DVD.

[Source](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/rollback-from-windows-10)

**For Windows 10 Preview**

From the [preview.windows.com site's FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/preview-faq#faq=tab0):

> **If you want to go back to your previous operating system**
>
> You'll need to reinstall your version of Windows from the recovery or
>   installation media that came with your PC (typically DVD media). If
>   you don't have recovery media:
>
> For Windows 7 or Windows Vista: Before you update, you might be able
>   to create recovery media from a recovery partition on your PC using
>   software provided by your PC manufacturer. Check the support section
>   of your PC manufacturer's website for more info.
>
> For Windows 8.1 or Windows 8: You might be able to create a USB
>   recovery drive. For more info, see Create a USB recovery drive.

Short version: there's no way to "Downgrade", you need to reinstall your previous OS from scratch or from a backup.

*Edit:*

In later versions (and in the final build) if you upgraded, you can revert back to you previous OS for 1 month via **Settings** > **Update & security** > **Recovery** > **Go Back to Windows (version #)**.

Source: [Recovery options in Windows 10](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows-10/windows-10-recovery-options)

Comment: One should point out that the "recovery drive" or "recovery media" is WinRE no matter what version of Windows your dealing with so unless you actually create an image before the upgrade booting to the WinRE isn't going to do much good.

Comment: Doesn't this assume that he has replaced his old version of Windows with Windows 10? What happens if he dual-booted his OS? Then what should he do?

Comment: @Ahkam Nihardeen then the guy who asked the question wouldn't call it downgrade...

Comment: @RahulBasu Its possible that he got Windows 10, and installed as a dual boot, and that he doesn't know that that the other Windows was still installed (as it defaults to 10, seemingly making it that it's completely gone). He wants to remove 10 and get 8/7. In this case, he would got to the Windows 8 partition, delete the boot entry for 10, and format the partition.

Answer (score 6):

I installed Win 10 Preview from the web installer and have an option to 'Go back to Windows 7' in

```
'Settings > Update & Security > Recovery'
```

along with the 'Reset this PC' option.

[image]

It might be different if you installed from the ISO image though.