# Uninstall Windows 10 Tech Preview (reverting back to Windows 8.1)

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1

So, I recently installed the Windows 10 Technology Preview as a full installation (not update, the setup didn't allow me to do it even if I had the same OS language). Now I'd like to revert back to my previous installation.

**I tried first recovering with my recovery USB**, however this doesn't seem to work. When I boot from drive and try to restore, the setup tells my that the recovery can't be applied to "Windows 10 Technical Preview".

All I got now is a "Windows.old". Is it possible to restore from that? What about registry etc?

Resources:

[How do I Uninstall Windows 10 or Windows 10 preview?](https://superuser.com/questions/819355/how-do-i-uninstall-windows-10-preview)

http://www.thewindowsclub.com/uninstall-windows-10-technical-preview

Comment: Its not possible to "uninstall" an operating system.  You can restore a system image but that's restoring the image not "reverting" Windows back to 8.1.  `Windows.old` only contains the programs and personal files the installer was unable to migrate it does not contain the information required to do what you want ( which again isn't possible ).

Answer (score 0):

You can't go back!

You won't be able to use your recovery partition to downgrade from Windows 10 to Windows 8.1 or similar.

If you have a recovery partition on your system, it will no longer be able to restore your computer to the version of Windows you had before.

And, as you'd expect from a system with no recovery partition, you'll need to install a previous version of Windows from a DVD or USB drive when it comes to overwriting or wiping your Windows 10 install.

Comment: A recovery partition can be used to restore the Windows 8.1 installation.  It just won't be the same installation, personal files and x86/x64 desktop applications will be uninstalled, and application settings will be lost.

Comment: I stand by my comment, ramhound perhaps you would care to detail your comment with a guide as to how you believe this is achievable. Microsoft official line also on this is as follows :
You'll need to reinstall your version of Windows from the recovery or installation media that came with your PC (typically DVD media). If you don't have recovery media: 

For Windows 8.1 or Windows 8: You might be able to create a USB recovery drive. For more info, see Create a USB recovery drive. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/preview-faq#faq=tab0 But please do explain if I and they are wrong?

Comment: You can of course re-import the windows.old file once you have a usable version of Windows re-installed!

Comment: But `Windows.old` will only contain the files or applications that were not migrated during the upgrade.  Even then those applications would still need to be reinstalled.