# How do I restore my Surface 3 after installing Windows 10 Tech Preview

Tags: reinstall, microsoft-surface, windows-10-preview

Before installing the Windows 10 Tech Preview, I created a *recovery media* on an USB stick, so that I could [completely reset my Surface 3](https://superuser.com/questions/819355/how-do-i-uninstall-windows-10-preview) and repave it with Windows 8.1, should I need to.

After the last update, my Windows 10 Tech Preview no longer connected to my wifi, so I decided to reset the PC. I expected that following [these instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-us/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/restore-refresh-or-reset-surface-pro#usb) would allow me to restore my Surface 3 to a working Windows 8.1 environment.

However, after **step 9** (tapping *Yes, repartition the drives*) I get stuck with a message telling me to insert the Windows installation media. *Cancel* is the only available option at that point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally found the solution [here](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-remove-windows-10-technical-preview-your-surface-pro-3).

In order to reinstall Windows 8.1 from the *Surface Pro 3 recovery media*, I have to **clean** the disk first, wiping any partitions which were confusing the reinstallation process.

1. First create a bootable USB disk with the recovery media.
    Without this **recovery media** you won't be able to reinstall your Surface.
2. Insert the USB stick with the recovery media.
3. Press and hold the *Volume Down* button while turning the Surface on. As soon as the Surface logo
    appears, release the *Volume Down* button.
4. Select Troubleshoot > Advanced Options > Command Prompt.
5. Start `diskpart` and execute `select disk system`, followed by `clean` and `exit`.
6. Reboot the Surface again and use the standard *Reset your PC* procedure.

Comment: Oh, I was doing it for hours until I realized that it's **disk** with a "k" and not **disc** with a "c". Now it went all the way. Of course, I don't have the USB so I only can enter BIOS...   :(

Comment: Ah, yes: **disk** applies to magnetic disk drives whereas **disc** would be used for optical ones (compact disc). See also this article explaining the difference between disk and disc: http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201697

Comment: Awesome (+1). You might add to the first part of your answer to **make a bootable USB** before cleaning. You should write it **twice**. Some people don't do that and those people can only access the BIOS afterwards feeling like an ass. I'm those people right now, hehe.