# Reinstall Surface without USB backup

Tags: windows-10-preview, microsoft-surface-pro-3

Following [some hints](https://superuser.com/a/852355/161760), I cleaned up my disc and wish to install/reinstall Win 10. The problem is that I don't have any installation media and as it's now, I only can enter BIOS, not anything "prettier" in the system.

What do I do with that?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download a recovery Image from Microsoft on a 2nd system and create a recovery drive:

**Download a recovery image for your Surface**
http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-US/support/warranty-service-and-recovery/downloadablerecoveryimage