# Unable to revert Windows 10 after upgrading to Windows 10 Pro

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have followed [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/819371/156554), but I don't see option `Go Back to Windows 8.1`, just the `Reset this PC` and `Advanced start-up`. What am I missing? Why is this option gone?

Is it because over 30 days has passed since installing Windows 10 Home?

Few days ago I've entered a different product key (legal, activated) and thus changed my Windows 10 Home into Windows 10 Pro. Can this be the source of my problem?

If that's the case, is there any rollback solution or do I have a clean install as the only option?

Comment: how long ago did you upgrade from 8.1 to 10?

Comment: Updated question. Win 8.1 HE -> Win 10 HE was about 3 months ago. Win 10 HE -> Win 10 Pro about 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your edit answered the question.  Windows only keeps the ability to rollback for 30 days.

Comment: ...meaning, that fresh install is the only option in my case, right?

Comment: if you want to go back to 8.1, then yes...